# Creating an app for the iPhone (including iPhone 5) that plays videos

Tags: iphone, video, iphone-5

We're about to build an app that plays a bunch of videos on the iPhone.

But we're wondering what the best practice is going to be given the new iPhone 5 screen.

We are going to have to output the videos at either 960 x 640 (traditional iPhone display) or 1136 x 640 (iPhone 5).

Either way we're going to have black bars horizontally or vertically.

We'll have around 300MB of videos.

Any suggestions on how we best tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest encoding for the larger size and letting those with the smaller display deal with the black bars. Why? Because it is a guarantee that iPhones < iPhone 5 will decrease over time and that iPhones >= iPhone 5 will increase. If you are going to have black bars either way (encoding twice and choosing which one based on hardware is an option, though it might be impractical) you might as well plan for the future.